# The same build event on different version Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I checked out a project from TFS, which created by my colleague on visual studio 2013. This project have a build event event in which it is calling a .exe from the path "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`"

However, I am working at Visual Studio 2017 (not install visual studio 2013), the path of .exe has changed to other path. So I need change the path in the build command line. When I submit my code to TFS, my code could not be used by others in visual studi 2013.

So my question is How can I use the same build event on different version Visual Studio? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What `.exe`? Put it into location which will not depend on VS version or local installation of VS. Another option is to use [`Path`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

Comment: You just can't, VS2017 made changes that are entirely too drastic to the location of the kind of tools you might want to use in a build event.  There is very little point in not showing us what it looks like btw, nobody can propose an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The same build event on different version Visual Studio

If I understand you correct, you do not want to switch back and forth to the path of the called .exe when you use build event on different versions of VS. An I right?

Just as Hans said, you can not use same build event on different version Visual Studio, but I would like provide a workaround, you can check if it what you want:

You can use **the property of "`VisualStudioVersion`" in the build event to choose the different path of .exe**. In the Visual Studio 2013, the value of `VisualStudioVersion` is `12.0`. In the Visual Studio 2017, the value is `15.0`. So the detail build event should like below:

```
if "$(VisualStudioVersion)" == "12.0" (cell YourExePath="ThePathOfExeInVS2013\Your.exe")

if "$(VisualStudioVersion)" == "15.0" (cell YourExePath="ThePathOfExeInVS2017\Your.exe")
```

Since you are not give the detailed path of that exe, I created the test sample with below script:

```
if "$(VisualStudioVersion)" == "12.0" (echo "This command line come from VS 2013!")

if "$(VisualStudioVersion)" == "15.0" (echo "This command line come from VS 2017!")
```

It works fine in Visual Studio 2017 and 2013:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, your workaround is useful. I accept this as answer until I find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a Powershell script that computes where is the tool, e.g.

```
"%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file "$(SolutionDir)myscript.ps1"
```

the script itself goes along this line

```
function Get-VisualStudioInstallDir
{
    if ($env:ProgramW6432) {
        # 64 bit
        $registryBase = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft"
    } else {
        # 32 bit
        $registryBase = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft"
    }
    if (Test-Path "$registryBase\VisualStudio") {
        $highestVSversion = "{0:N1}" -f (Get-ChildItem -Path "$registryBase\VisualStudio" | Split-Path -Leaf | foreach { $_ -as [double] } | sort -Descending | select -First 1)    
        $vsPath = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$registryBase\VisualStudio\$highestVSversion" -Name InstallDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($vsPath) {
            $vsPath.InstallDir
        }
    }
}

$tf= Join-Path (Get-VisualStudioInstallDir) -ChildPath 'tf.exe'
& $tf /help
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I`m not good at PS. I will check it after I learn some PS.